# OpenCart текущая версия сайта

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.0

Есть сайт на `Opencart` . Мне нужно изменить 2 класса на странице каталога товаров. Установлена тема `sstore`, поэтому я иду в

`catalog/view/theme/sstore/template/`.

Там покопался, нашёл тот блок, который мне нужен в product/category.tpl. Изменяю классы, сохраняю, заливаю на сервер, ничего не происходит. Классы те же. Ну я решил изменить и `category1_.tpl` и `category2_.tpl`, они лежат рядом и у них есть тот самый блок. Тоже ничего не изменилось. В `category.tpl` добавил перед названием продукта "123" в теге p, ничего нет тоже.

Выходит, что я не то изменяю, что ли?

Comment: Через что загружаешь на сервер? Попытайся на прямую через filezilla сохранить tpl файл.

Comment: Через filezilla всё делаю

Comment: Может быть ошибка в шаблонизаторе , внимательно проверь код

Comment: Даже хз, всё в порядке. Может в админке что-то изменить можно?

Answer (score 0):

Па-Та-Му-Чта кеши расширений после внесений изменений вы скорее всего не почистили. Это в модули/расширения-модификаторы и там кнопочки в правом верхнем углу.